# Ajax Not Executed

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am beginner to ajax world and trying to call contents from php page using $.ajax() function and the code couldn't executed. the html page i used:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>AJAX</title>    
</head>
<body>

<div >    
    <input type="text" name="search" id="search">       
    <br>
    <br>
    <h2 id="result"></h2>
</div>    
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"   integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

the JQuery code i used in the script.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#search').keyup(function () {
        var search = $('#search').val();

        $.ajax({

            url:'search.php',
            //the page to which the request will go to

            data:{search: search},

            type: 'POST',
            success:function(data) {
                if(!data.error){
                    $('#result').html(data);//the h2 we want to echo it uing the ajax
                }
            }

        });

    });

});
```

the search.php page contain:

```
$search = $_POST['search'];
echo $search;
```

the code not executed. What should I do.

Comment: which code isn't executed? JS? PHP? done any basic debugging, like checking if the keyup ever triggers? checked your webserver's log to see if a request ever reached the server?

Comment: What's not working specifically? Is the `keyup` event not firing? Is the request getting an error response code? Is the PHP script failing in some way?

Comment: when Iam typing in the input the value enterd in the input not printed in the empty h2 element @Marc B & @ CollinD 4

Comment: `data.error` doesn't exist. You're returning a simple string. not json, and even if you were returning json, didn't tell jquery.ajax() to EXPECT json.

Comment: try just `if (data != "")` or whatever.

Comment: yes i tested the keyup event to alert value entered in the input and it is executed proberly. @MarcB

Comment: any errors in the developer console in the browser?

Comment: Did you test printing something on your php script? mayabe your post var on php is empyt

Comment: @MarcB Thanks dear. I used `if (data != "")` and the problem solved. Thank you so much.

Comment: As an aside to all of the above comments, are you aware of the load that will be put on your server with code like this? Ajaxing on each keyup for every user typing in their instance of the search box...you'll be lucky if your server survives the barriage of requests that will be thrown it's way.

Comment: @War10ck, just for training not something else.

Comment: @MohamedMahmoudElkassas, it is not very nice to [delete questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39054578/java-script-newline-replacement/39054626?noredirect=1#comment65458631_39054626) once answers have been given. What you should do is accept an answer (or provide comments so answers can be improved).

Answer (score 1):

I see some issue in your response from PHP code and in ajax side success code.

You are not sending in response JSON format so data.error is meaningless.
so in your success callback code should be like this.

```
success:function(data) {
    $('#result').html(data);//the h2 we want to echo it uing the ajax
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow jQuery Ajax Document :

An alias for method. You should use type if you're using versions of jQuery prior to 1.9.0

```
type: 'POST'
```

But you are using 2.0 so i think this will work :

```
method: 'POST'
```

[jQuery Documents](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)