# java script newline replacement

Tags: javascript, loops, newline

I finished a JavaScript beginners course and tried to solve the JS challenges in hackthissite.org. in last challenge the obfuscation decryption done correctly but the for loop i executed, output letters below each other instead of beside each other.

```
var puzzle = [0x3c, 0x62, 0x75, 0x74, 0x74, 0x6f, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x6f, 0x6e, 0x63, 0x6c, 0x69, 0x63, 0x6b, 0x3d, 0x27, 0x6a, 0x61, 0x76, 0x61, 0x73, 0x63, 0x72, 0x69, 0x70, 0x74, 0x3a, 0x69, 0x66, 0x20, 0x28, 0x64, 0x6f, 0x63, 0x75, 0x6d, 0x65, 0x6e, 0x74, 0x2e, 0x67, 0x65, 0x74, 0x45, 0x6c, 0x65, 0x6d, 0x65, 0x6e, 0x74, 0x42, 0x79, 0x49, 0x64, 0x28, 0x22, 0x70, 0x61, 0x73, 0x73, 0x22, 0x29, 0x2e, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6c, 0x75, 0x65, 0x3d, 0x3d, 0x22, 0x6a, 0x30, 0x30, 0x77, 0x31, 0x6e, 0x22, 0x29, 0x7b, 0x61, 0x6c, 0x65, 0x72, 0x74, 0x28, 0x22, 0x59, 0x6f, 0x75, 0x20, 0x57, 0x49, 0x4e, 0x21, 0x22, 0x29, 0x3b, 0x77, 0x69, 0x6e, 0x64, 0x6f, 0x77, 0x2e, 0x6c, 0x6f, 0x63, 0x61, 0x74, 0x69, 0x6f, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x2b, 0x3d, 0x20, 0x22, 0x3f, 0x6c, 0x76, 0x6c, 0x5f, 0x70, 0x61, 0x73, 0x73, 0x77, 0x6f, 0x72, 0x64, 0x3d, 0x22, 0x2b, 0x64, 0x6f, 0x63, 0x75, 0x6d, 0x65, 0x6e, 0x74, 0x2e, 0x67, 0x65, 0x74, 0x45, 0x6c, 0x65, 0x6d, 0x65, 0x6e, 0x74, 0x42, 0x79, 0x49, 0x64, 0x28, 0x22, 0x70, 0x61, 0x73, 0x73, 0x22, 0x29, 0x2e, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6c, 0x75, 0x65, 0x7d, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x73, 0x65, 0x20, 0x7b, 0x61, 0x6c, 0x65, 0x72, 0x74, 0x28, 0x22, 0x57, 0x52, 0x4f, 0x4e, 0x47, 0x21, 0x20, 0x54, 0x72, 0x79, 0x20, 0x61, 0x67, 0x61, 0x69, 0x6e, 0x21, 0x22, 0x29, 0x7d, 0x27, 0x3e, 0x43, 0x68, 0x65, 0x63, 0x6b, 0x20, 0x50, 0x61, 0x73, 0x73, 0x77, 0x6f, 0x72, 0x64, 0x3c, 0x2f, 0x62, 0x75, 0x74, 0x74, 0x6f, 0x6e, 0x3e],
    i;

for (i = 0; i < puzzle.length; i++) {

    console.log(String.fromCharCode(puzzle[i]).replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, ""));
}
```

Any trick could solve that !!

Comment: console.log is called multiple times logging one character per line. That's what you need to change.

Comment: `console.log(String.fromCharCode.apply(String, puzzle))`

Comment: @squint good one pro (y).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of logging the result of each character, concatenate them to a result variable, and then output that, once:

```js
var puzzle = [0x3c, 0x62, 0x75, 0x74, 0x74, 0x6f, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x6f, 0x6e, 0x63, 0x6c, 0x69, 0x63, 0x6b, 0x3d, 0x27, 0x6a, 0x61, 0x76, 0x61, 0x73, 0x63, 0x72, 0x69, 0x70, 0x74, 0x3a, 0x69, 0x66, 0x20, 0x28, 0x64, 0x6f, 0x63, 0x75, 0x6d, 0x65, 0x6e, 0x74, 0x2e, 0x67, 0x65, 0x74, 0x45, 0x6c, 0x65, 0x6d, 0x65, 0x6e, 0x74, 0x42, 0x79, 0x49, 0x64, 0x28, 0x22, 0x70, 0x61, 0x73, 0x73, 0x22, 0x29, 0x2e, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6c, 0x75, 0x65, 0x3d, 0x3d, 0x22, 0x6a, 0x30, 0x30, 0x77, 0x31, 0x6e, 0x22, 0x29, 0x7b, 0x61, 0x6c, 0x65, 0x72, 0x74, 0x28, 0x22, 0x59, 0x6f, 0x75, 0x20, 0x57, 0x49, 0x4e, 0x21, 0x22, 0x29, 0x3b, 0x77, 0x69, 0x6e, 0x64, 0x6f, 0x77, 0x2e, 0x6c, 0x6f, 0x63, 0x61, 0x74, 0x69, 0x6f, 0x6e, 0x20, 0x2b, 0x3d, 0x20, 0x22, 0x3f, 0x6c, 0x76, 0x6c, 0x5f, 0x70, 0x61, 0x73, 0x73, 0x77, 0x6f, 0x72, 0x64, 0x3d, 0x22, 0x2b, 0x64, 0x6f, 0x63, 0x75, 0x6d, 0x65, 0x6e, 0x74, 0x2e, 0x67, 0x65, 0x74, 0x45, 0x6c, 0x65, 0x6d, 0x65, 0x6e, 0x74, 0x42, 0x79, 0x49, 0x64, 0x28, 0x22, 0x70, 0x61, 0x73, 0x73, 0x22, 0x29, 0x2e, 0x76, 0x61, 0x6c, 0x75, 0x65, 0x7d, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x73, 0x65, 0x20, 0x7b, 0x61, 0x6c, 0x65, 0x72, 0x74, 0x28, 0x22, 0x57, 0x52, 0x4f, 0x4e, 0x47, 0x21, 0x20, 0x54, 0x72, 0x79, 0x20, 0x61, 0x67, 0x61, 0x69, 0x6e, 0x21, 0x22, 0x29, 0x7d, 0x27, 0x3e, 0x43, 0x68, 0x65, 0x63, 0x6b, 0x20, 0x50, 0x61, 0x73, 0x73, 0x77, 0x6f, 0x72, 0x64, 0x3c, 0x2f, 0x62, 0x75, 0x74, 0x74, 0x6f, 0x6e, 0x3e],
    i,
    result = '';
    
for (i = 0; i < puzzle.length; i++) {
    result += String.fromCharCode(puzzle[i]).replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm, "");
}
console.log(result);
```

Depending on the result you expect: maybe the replacement of newlines is now no longer necessary?